# Diamond Renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I currently have a diamond stud earring on a character I am making. My current render scene has a very typical 3 point (with some additional lights here and there to ease shadows) setup. It's a direct facing portrait shot.

At the moment my diamond isn't really.... glimmering / looking white and sparkly (for lack of better terms)... Do any of you have a clever way of cheating this? I am aware that a diamond is only as good as it's envi / things to reflect... hence why I was wondering? Was considering maybe using an HDRI on low strength or something but figured I would ask here first to see if you guys have already solved this problem

Final render will be in Cycles

[image: SHADER NODE]

[image: CYCLES VIEWPORT]

[image: EEVEE VIEWPORT]

Comment: Hi :). Yes, a high-contrast HDRI is exactly what you need

Comment: There's also a tutorial on procedural crystal materials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9bl4VhVcD4) which might help.

Comment: Thank you for the replies I will look into this tutorial and fiddle with some HDRIs